# Move src/ directory into subfolder - ant fails to generate .classes

Tags: android, eclipse, ant

**Ok, solution was to add source.dir=platforms/src in ant.properties file!**

I've currently a directory containing the following:

> AndroidManifest.xml  assets/  build.xml  libs/  local.properties 
>   proguard-project.txt  project.properties  res/  src/

However, I'd like to move "src" directory into a subfolder, let's say "platforms":

> AndroidManifest.xml  assets/  build.xml  libs/  local.properties 
>   platforms/ proguard-project.txt  project.properties  res/

When building the project in Eclipse, everything works fine. However when I am using ant to generate the classes path, it fails:

```
BUILD FAILED
/opt/android-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/android-bundle-linux/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:659:
/path-to-application/src does not exist.
```

My .classpath looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="platforms/src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry exported="true" kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.DEPENDENCIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

File build.xml: http://pastebin.com/AVD9xuPa

To sum up, is this even possible to move src/ folder for ant?

Thanks

PS: making a symbolic link from platforms/src to src is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is certainly possible.  However, the complaint you are getting may not be related to the `classpath` at all:

```
/path-to-application/src does not exist.
```

Either you need to manually create the directory, correct the path, or add a `mkdir` in your ant file prior to that line getting called.

Comment: Yes obviously I could create an empty 'src' folder, but ant won't get the files from the real path anyway. Thus they will be missing in bin/classes generated directory.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if that's the directory where it is trying to find your source files. Without the full build.xml file it's difficult to understand what it is trying to do with that directory.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question and added build.xml (which is the default one, generated by android update command line).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand a little better now. First question, did the ant build work prior to relocating the src directory? Second, have you made any modifications to any of the ant build files to accommodate this new directory location?

Comment: Yes if src/ does contain source files, everything's ok. And I did not modify any of ant configuration files, should I? Actually I expected the android update command to do it

Comment: Well, ok, thanks for pointing this out, I needed to create ant.properties file, with source.dir=platforms/src inside!